# Sub-panel without any loads

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

I sold a hot tub that was on my property when I purchased it.  There is a 240V sub-panel that powered the hot tub and it has one double-pole breaker.

With the hot tub going away, what should I be doing with this sub-panel since I'm left with no load on it.

Should I just switch the single breaker off in the sub-panel?  Should I also switch off the breaker at the main panel that feeds the sub-panel?  Or should I be removing the breaker at the main panel altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shut off the breaker feeding that subpanel and label it as "Keep OFF", unless you intend to reuse the subpanel for something else.  Leave it wired in for now, as you may sell the house and someone else will want that hot tub plug right where you left it.

Comment: The other options are: to pull the breaker from the main panel and installing a cover plug - which means taking down power to the main panel; or, purchase a lock-out kit from Graybar, which literally prevents the breaker from being used, and it has a tiny lock on it, or a set of holes to install a lock through it.

Answer (score 3):

Just shut it off in the main panel.

Or... Change out the main panel breaker to 20A. 
Put a pair of duplex receptacles fed off the hot tub subpanel breaker.  *The breaker in the main panel provides overcurrent protection for the receptacles.   The breaker in the hot tub panel provides GFCI*.

Comment: Just make sure you don't wire the receptacles up at 240V, otherwise your drill will shoot sparks.